# Unit Testing Role Access to a Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

How would i go about testing whether an authorize attribute on  method or controller in a WebApi/MVC project has a specific role(s)

So i could test a method doing something like the below?

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase("Put", new []{"Admin","TeamMember"})]
    [TestCase("Post", new []{"Admin","TeamMember"})]
    [TestCase("Get", new []{"TeamMember"})]

    public void Ensure_Methods_have_Correct_Roles(string methodToTest, List<string> roles)
    {
        var controller = new myController();
        Assert.IsTrue(controller.HasRoles(methodToTest, roles));
    }
```

with the has Roles extension method being stubbed out like this

```
    public static bool HasRoles(this Controller controller, string action, string[] roles)
    {
        var controllerType = controller.GetType();
        var method = controllerType.GetMethod(action);

        object[] filters = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizationAttribute), true);

        if(!filters.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(AuthorizationAttribute))
        {
            throw exception()
        }

        var rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute = // This is where i'm stuck

        foreach(var role in rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute)
        {
           //pseudo-code
           if(!roles.contains(role)
           {
               return false;
           }
        }
        return true;

    }
```

is this even sensible or should i be testing the controller action directly and testing whether the response is a 401/403? That would require mocking up a context though and would mean more testing code since i would have to test each method separately.

EDIT: Perhaps don't focus on whether it's sensible. Just is it doable?

My thinking was that the unit tests would be the canonical specification of what actions should have what roles (since there is currently no written spec, and probably won't ever have one). If a developer changes a role, then they need to have a good reason for it.

EDIT #2

Based on Con's Answer below, this is what i've ended up with, one method to check aan action, another to check the controller.

```
 public static bool WebApiActionHasRoles(this ApiController controller, string action, string roles)
    {
        var controllerType = controller.GetType();
        var method = controllerType.GetMethod(action);

        object[] filters = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute), true);

        if (!filters.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute = filters.SelectMany(attrib => ((System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute)attrib).Roles.Split(new[] { ',' })).ToList();
        var rolesToCheckAgainst = roles.Split(',').ToList();

        return !rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute.Except(rolesToCheckAgainst).Any() && !rolesToCheckAgainst.Except(rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute).Any();
    }

    public static bool WebApiControllerHasRoles(this ApiController controller, string roles)
    {
        var controllerType = controller.GetType();


        object[] filters = controllerType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute), true);

        if (!filters.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute = filters.SelectMany(attrib => ((System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute)attrib).Roles.Split(new[] { ',' })).ToList();
        var rolesToCheckAgainst = roles.Split(',').ToList();
        return !rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute.Except(rolesToCheckAgainst).Any() && !rolesToCheckAgainst.Except(rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute).Any();
    }
```

If you want to use it with MVC  instead of Web Api controllers/Actions just change the `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` to `System.Web.MVC.AuthorizeAttribute` and in the Method Signature change `ApiController` to `Controller`

Comment: From your code, I reckon all you are doing is testing whether the AuthorizeAttribute works, which is Microsoft's responsibility. An integration test to assert that you get a 401/403 for peace of mind is good - but testing one controller action would probably be enough.

Comment: I disagree. I'm testing that a specific method has a specified set of roles. Or at least that's what I'm trying to do...:)

Comment: I thought of that too. If you are going to change the roles of a method, its probably something you are intending to do and you are just causing unnecessary work by having to make sure the Tests are now matching the change.

Comment: I see the value in having unit test around allowed role. Better to have a unit test failed (and fixed) when an unintentional change in allowed role happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to `AuthorizeAttribute` vs `AuthorizationAttribute`, is this what you need:

```
    public static bool HasRoles(this Controller controller, string action, string[] roles)
    {
        var controllerType = controller.GetType();
        var method = controllerType.GetMethod(action);

        object[] filters = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true);

        if(!filters.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var rolesOnCurrentMethodsAttribute = filters.SelectMany(attrib => ((AuthorizeAttribute)attrib).Roles.Split(new[] { ',' })).ToList();

        return roles.Except(rolesInMethod).Count() == 0 && rolesInMethod.Except(roles).Count() == 0;
    }
```

Alternatively, if you want to make your tests stricter and enforce only one Authorize attribute per action:

```
public static bool HasRoles(this Controller controller, string action, string roles)
{
    var controllerType = controller.GetType();
    var method = controllerType.GetMethod(action);
    var attrib = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as AuthorizeAttribute;
    if (attrib == null)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return attrib.Roles == roles;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, will test in the morning

Comment: Great, cheers worked a treat. I made a couple of modifications to the signature and body and posted it in my question.